# Prime Number for n value

Tags: excel, vba

**Task:** A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive
divisors other than 1 and itself. Here are the first few prime numbers:

`2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31...`

Define a function that, given an integer n, determines the first n prime
numbers.

**Problem:** I am currently getting the primes between 0-n but not n prime numbers.

My code is:

```vb
    Sub MACRO()
    Z = InputBox("enter number")
        Dim x As Long, n As Long, i As Long, PrimeNumber As Long
        x = 0
            With ActiveSheet
            For n = 1 To Z
            For i = 2 To n - 1
                    If n Mod i = 0 Then
                        x = 0
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        x = 1
                    End If
                Next
                If x = 1 Then
                    PrimeNumber = PrimeNumber + 1
                .Cells(PrimeNumber, 1) = n
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: You are iterating in the wrong way, indeed you stop at n. But if you want n results instead you have to use a different cycle, like "while", counting the numbers that are found.

Comment: No need to test any even numbers, so start at 3 and use `Step 2` in your loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When searching for Primes, you speed thing up by observing:

- You only need to test Odd numbers
- You can exclude a test for divisibility by 2
- You only need to test for divisibility by previously found prime numbers
- You only need to test up to the square root of the candidate number

Something like this

```
Sub FindPrimes(NumPrimes As Long, Primes() As Long)
    Dim Candidate As Long, Factor As Long
    Dim idxP As Long
    Dim IsPrime As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    ReDim Primes(1 To NumPrimes)

    Primes(1) = 2
    Primes(2) = 3

    idxP = 3
    Candidate = 3

    Do While idxP <= NumPrimes
        Candidate = Candidate + 2
        i = 2
        IsPrime = True
        Do
            Factor = Candidate \ Primes(i)
            ' Factor < Primes(i) implies Primes(i) > Sqrt(Candidate)
            If Factor < Primes(i) Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            If Factor * Primes(i) = Candidate Then
                IsPrime = False
                Exit Do
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        If IsPrime Then
            Primes(idxP) = Candidate
            idxP = idxP + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Use it like this

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim Primes() As Long
    Dim Num As Long

    FindPrimes Num, Primes

    ' Primes is now an array of the first Num primes
End Sub
```

On my hardware, this finds the first 10,000 primes in 50ms  (FWIW, compared to Foxfire's answer which takes 10s)

Comment: Extremely fast and a helpful summary of essential rules or limitations concerning primes. - Regarding the last point `"You only need to test up to the square root of the candidate number"` and as I don't see a square root calculation, I suppose this is built in implicitly in the factor comparisons. Maybe worth a short explanation :+)

Answer (score 2):

For this code to work, you need to add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` from Tools->References

[image]

Iterate from 1 to number studied.

```
Dim n As Integer
Dim i As Double
Dim MyStart As Double
Dim zz As Integer
Dim MyPrimes As Dictionary
Dim MyKey As Variant

n = 10 'change this to get n prime numbers

Set MyPrimes = New Dictionary

zz = 0
i = 1

Do Until zz = n
    For MyStart = 1 To i Step 1
        If i / MyStart = Int(i / MyStart) Then
            'check if it's prime
            If MyStart = i Then
                'it's prime. we check the dictionary. If it does not exist, we add it and update count
                If MyPrimes.Exists(MyStart) = False And MyStart<>1 Then
                    MyPrimes.Add MyStart, MyStart
                    zz = MyPrimes.Count
                End If
            Else
                'it is not prime. Quit Loop if divisor it's not 1
                If MyStart <> 1 Then Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next MyStart
    i = i + 1
Loop

For Each MyKey In MyPrimes.Keys
    Debug.Print MyPrimes(MyKey)
Next MyKey

MyPrimes.RemoveAll
Set MyPrimes = Nothing
```

In the debug windows i Get:

```
 1 
 2 
 3 
 5 
 7 
 11 
 13 
 17 
 19 
 23
```

Just change n and test it. Hope this helps

**UPDATE**: As @PeH said, 1 is not prime, my bad,so I updated code to ignore number 1 :)

**UPDATE 2:** As @PeH suggested, you can also `Dim MyPrime As Object` and then use late binding `Set MyPrime = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`.

*Advantage:* you don't need to add Microsoft Scripting Runtime and if you use it on different computers with different versions of the runtime it will still work.

*Disatvantage:* you lose intelli sense in the VBA editor (for this object only).

> In case you want to know how dictionaries work: [Excel VBA Dictionary– A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/)

Comment: Thank you but the MyPrime as Dictionary is not working in mine

Comment: @Shabby my fail, I totally forgot to mention that you need to add a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`. I'm sorry

Comment: @Pᴇʜ You are absolutely right, my bad. I updated the code to ignore number 1, sorry about that

Comment: @Shabby You can also `Dim MyPrime As Object` and then use late binding `Set MyPrime = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`. Advantage: you don't need to add `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` and if you use it on different computers with different versions of the runtime it will still work. Disatvantage: you lose intelli sense in the VBA editor (for this object only). In case you want to know how dictionaries work: [Excel VBA Dictionary – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thank you. I did that but I keep getting the error '424": Object required, I am using Excel - Visual Basic for Applications

Comment: @Shabby in which line of the code? If you don't tell the line the error message is pretty meaningless. Anyway this code works check again if you have exactly what we suggested.